# Parse CSV containing list in a column

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, csv, import-from-csv

I have a CSV file that I generated through a [`csv.writer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) object. Here is a simplified version of the code to generate the file:

```
output = open('out.txt', 'ab+')
writer = csv.writer(output, dialect='excel')

for item in dataset:
    row = []
    row.append(item['id'])
    row.append(item['timestamp'])

    values = []
    for value in item['values']
        values.append(value['name'])
    row.append(values)

    writer.writerow(row)
    output.flush()

output.close()
```

A sample row in the CSV file looks like this:

```
457458856894140182,Mon Dec 02 11:36:48 +0000 2013,[u'Sugar', u'Rice', u'Bleach']
```

I've tried using a [`csv.reader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) object to parse the  data back into another script, but haven't been able to correctly parse the list in the third column. Python just sees the entire value `[u'Sugar', u'Rice', u'Bleach']` as a string. For example, the code:

```
input = open('out.txt', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(input, dialect='excel')

for row in reader:
    print row[2][0]

input.close()
```

...just outputs a long list of `[` on newlines.

How can I parse this CSV file correctly, to get assemble the structure in the third column back into a list in memory?

Comment: Are you permitted to change the format it's written in?  Right now the way you're doing it doesn't quote the commas in your list, so it'd be better to either write them as a combined quoted object or to give each member of the list its own column.  (Aside: that can't be your code -- there's a missing colon in the inner for loop.  Please always copy and paste the code you're using exactly.)

Comment: I can change the format for future CSVs, yes, but unfortunately there is no way for me to change the format for the CSVs that have already been generated. And no, it isn't my exact code as my exact code is a couple of hundred lines long. I was aiming to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: An SSCCE can't have syntax errors, and should be self-contained. :^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the string `[u'Sugar', u'Rice', u'Bleach']` you can get the corresponding `list` object with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> a="[u'Sugar', u'Rice', u'Bleach']"
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
[u'Sugar', u'Rice', u'Bleach']
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)[1]
u'Rice'
>>>
```